# Copy context and formatting of a WORD document by VBA code in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

In `EXCEL`, I have some `VBA` codes to open a Word Document A and copy its content from certain page to a new document. Currently, I can copy its text. I am wondering how to copy both `context` and `formatting`. Below is my current code and I appreciate any suggestions!

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

objWord.Visible = True
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

'Prepare Document B
objDoc.SaveAs (Folderpath to Document B)

Set objTempWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set tempDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Folderpath to Document A)

'copy context from Document A        
With tempDoc.Application
     .Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:="2"
     .Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdExtend
     .Selection.Copy
End With

objSelection.TypeParagraph
objSelection.Paste
objSelection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
tempDoc.Close

objDoc.Application.Statusbar = False
objDoc.Save
```

Comment: Your code copied both text and formatting for me.  In you excel workbook, do you have a reference set to the Microsoft Word ##.# Object Library?

Comment: Why are you doing this: `Set objTempWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")` ?

Comment: @ThomasInzina, thanks for your comment. But I found the linespace is different (the font size remain the same).

Comment: I asking about a reference to the Microsoft Word ##.# Object Library, because your code will not work properly without it.  Excel is unaware of MS Word enumeration values: wdStory, wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute.

Comment: @ThomasInzina, yes. MS Word 15.0 Object Library is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

This here does the same, without the superfluous extra Application object and without the use of Selection:

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objDoc As Word.Document, newDoc As Word.Document
Dim r As Word.Range, r2 As Word.Range

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'or Set objWord = new Word.Application

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(FolderpathToDocumentA)
Set newDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
newDoc.SaveAs FolderpathToDocumentB

Set r = objDoc.GoTo(what:=wdGoToPage, which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=2)
r.End = objDoc.Range.End

'copy context from Document A
r.Copy
newDoc.Content.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
newDoc.Range(newDoc.Content.Start, newDoc.Content.Start).Paste
newDoc.Content.InsertBefore vbCrLf

newDoc.Save
objWord.Quit
```

Does that do what you need?

Comment: Thanks! Your version is much clean but still it only copied context without inheriting linespace...

Comment: I guess the magic word is "paragraph style". Is the document you're copying from using a Standard style that is different from the default Standard in line spacing? The new document will revert to default line spacing. Might want to copy over your paragraph style first.

Comment: Actually, I think your could be right. The original document was generated using a word template. I am trying to make a copy of that template and paste text to it.